# If statement with Match function in vba

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, match

I'm working on collection database, that can be used for sport cards. I'm nearly done with everything, but I have a problem with Match function in VBA. I tried to combine it with If statement, but if the Match function does not giving back a result, then the macro stops. Here is this part of the code:

```
Dim shortnamee As Integer
Dim ittkeres As Range
    Set ittkeres = Range("X:X") 
    shortnamee = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("V2"), ittkeres, 0)
    Range("V3") = shortnamee
    If Range("V3").Value > 0 Then
```

This part connects to the first page, where I can add new items to the collection sheets, and here it looks for duplicates from a concatenated name (V2 - the new items name; X:X - where the rest of the collection is, already uploaded.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but [Dictionaries](https://analystcave.com/excel-vba-dictionary-arrays-and-other-data-structures/) are a good way to check if some value exists. Because `Application.Match` taxes the execution way too much.

Comment: Thanks Damian. That is also a good idea, but I choose a different way.

Answer (score 0):

### Application.Match

- Rather use `Application.Match` which allows you to test its result with e.g. `IsError` or  `IsNumeric`.

```vb
Dim ittkeres As Range: Set ittkeres = Range("X:X")
Dim cIndex As Variant
cIndex = Application.Match(Range("V2").Value, ittkeres, 0)
If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
    Range("V3").Value = ittkeres.Cells(cIndex).Value
Else
    ' No match found.
End If
```